Find the equation of tangent through the point (3,4) on the circle $x^2+y^2 = 9$
radius = 3
Let $y-y_1 = m(x-x_1)$ be the equation of tangent.
Since, tangent passes through (3,4)

$or,\text{ }y - 4 = m(x - 3)$
$or,\text{ }y - 4 = mx - 3m$
$or,\text{ }mx +y - 3m + 4 = 0$
Thus, center of given circle is $(0,0)$. So, the perpendicular distance from the center to the tangent.
$or,\text{ }p = \big | \frac{ax_1 + by_1+c}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\big |$
$or,\text{ }p = \big | \frac{a.0 + b.0 +4-3m}{\sqrt{{m}^2+1^2}}\big |$
$or,\text{ }p = \big | \frac{4-3m}{\sqrt{{m}^2+1^2}}\big |$
$or,\text{ }p^2 = \frac{(4-3m)^2}{{{m}^2+1^2}}$
As perpendicular distance from tangent to center = radius of circle,
$or,\text{ }9m^2 + 9 = 16 + 9m^2 - 24m$
$or,\text{ }m = \frac{7}{24}$
I wonder why one solution only? and Solve this further

$m=\infty$ is also a solution

Is there any condition for one tangent line? It may have two tangent intersect with each other at (3, 4) and the point is outside of circle.

But when I tried to create tangent equation. I got a problem.

The line $x = 3$ is also tangent to the circle and passes through $(3,4)$, but is not of the form $y - y_1 = m(x-x_1)$.

Try drawing a picture

Please help me to solve this further by posting answer.

@AbhishekKharel, but Point(3,4) isn't on this circle.. So either the radius isn't 3, or you have a typo in the point coordinates.

@StanislavBashkyrtsev, no, it's not on the circle and it's not a typo.

@Ennar, the question states that the tangent needs to go through the point$(3,4)$ on the circle. So it's not just a line that passes through $(3,4)$ and is a tangent to the circle. Or maybe the question is simply phrased ambiguously ¯\(ツ)/¯

@StanislavBashkyrtsev it's poorly worded, but there is nothing mathematically problematic, it is obvious that we are trying to find all lines tangent to the circle $x^2+y^2 = 9$ that go through point $(3,4)$.

The equation $(y - y_1) = m (x - x_1)$ can represent all the lines in the plane except the "vertical" lines that are parallel to the $y$ axis. The second tangent is one of those lines. That's why you are getting only one value for $m$.

"Please help me to solve this further by posting answer." sounds like you just want us to post an answer so you can copy-paste it into your homework.

$(x^2+y^2-9)(3^2+4^2-9)-(3x+4y-9)^2 = (x - 3)(7 x - 24 y + 75)$

No that’s not my homework. I know that m=tan(90)=infinite but why doesn’t it shows in equations. Mind your word @jjagmath. It’s not for homework. I have already solve this just i got one solution. So, I was surprised and i was wondering it. So, I came here in this platform.

Let $(a,b)$ be a point on the circle $x^2+y^2 = 9$. Then the line $a(x-a)+b(y-b) = 0$ is line tangent to the circle that passes through point $(a,b)$. We also want point $(3,4)$ to be on the line $a(x-a)+b(y-b) = 0$ so we get system
\begin{align}
a(3-a)+b(4-b) &= 0\\
a^2+b^2 &= 9
\end{align}
If we expand the first equation we get $3a+4b-(a^2+b^2) = 0$ and substituting $a^2+b^2 = 9$, the system becomes
\begin{align}
3a+4b &= 9\\
a^2+b^2 &= 9
\end{align}
From the first equation we get $a = 3-\frac 43 b$, which you can substitute into the second equation and get two solutions $a=3,b=0$ and $a=-\frac{21}{25}, b=\frac{72}{25}$.
Finally, substitute that back into tangent line equation $a(x-a)+b(y-b) = 0$, first solution gives the line $3(x-3) + 0(y-0) = 0$, i.e. $x = 3$ and the second solution gives the line $-\frac{21}{25}(x+\frac{21}{25})+\frac{72}{25}(y-\frac{72}{25}) = 0$, i.e. $y = \frac 7{24}x+\frac{25}8.$


Your approach is correct and gives the tangent line $y = \frac 7{24}x+\frac{25}8$, but not the line $x = 3$. This is because you assumed that  tangent line is of the form $y-y_1 = m(x-x_1)$, but $x = 3$ is not of that form, so you only got one line. If you want to finish the exercise your way, you can repeat the process but assume that you have tangent line of the form $m(y-y_1) = x-x_1$. You should get $m = 0$.

I am actually busy right now but I will expand my answer later of you wish.
Use the $SS_1=T^2$ method and then factorise the resultant expression. You'll get both the tangents.

In this answer $S$ denotes the equation of circle, $S_1$ denotes the numerical value we get after putting the coordinate given in the equation of the circle and $T$ denotes the equation of chord of contact.
Proof click here

Would be great if you could expand this answer at some point, very curious :)

@StanislavBashkyrtsev this is what my comment to the question does


The fact that the $m^2$ term cancels from your equation indicates that $m=\infty$ is a valid solution. This value corresponds to the vertical tangent.

HINT
Calculus-based answer. I would start with noticing that
\begin{align*}
x^{2} + y^{2} = 9 \Rightarrow 2x + 2yy' = 0 \Rightarrow y' = -\frac{x}{y}
\end{align*}
Let $(x_{0},y_{0})\in \partial B_{3}(0)$. If $y_{0} = 0$, then $(x_{0},y_{0}) = (3,0)$ is a solution.
If $y_{0}\neq 0$, one gets the following system of equations to solve:
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
x^{2}_{0} + y^{2}_{0} = 9\\\\
y_{0} - 4 = -\dfrac{x_{0}}{y_{0}}(x_{0} - 3) 
\end{cases} & \Longleftrightarrow
\begin{cases}
x^{2}_{0} + y^{2}_{0} = 9\\\\
x^{2}_{0} + y^{2}_{0} - 3x_{0} - 4y_{0} = 0
\end{cases} \Longleftrightarrow
\begin{cases}
x^{2}_{0} + y^{2}_{0} = 9\\\\
3x_{0} + 4y_{0} = 9
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
Can you take it from here?
